# Update D3 tree when some nodes are removed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a tree as in [example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8324872).
When I remove some nodes, the tree should be updated. But I don't want to clean svg and redraw tree totally. Code to remove:

```
function click(d) {
  d.children = d.children[0].children[0].children;
  update(); // there is call inside to link.exit().remove(); and node.exit().remove();
}
```

The problem is that tree becomes broken(after removing C and D) :
[image]
[image]

Here is code - [JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/t0mhsauf/13/)

What is the best way to draw tree correctly without full redraw?

I tried to update depth, but did not help

```
function click(d) {
  d.children = d.children[0].children[0].children;
  d.children[d].depth =  d.children[d].depth -2;
  update(); // there is call inside to link.exit().remove(); and node.exit().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the update functions for the circles and links.

Since you only had add and remove, the elements were being added and removed properly, but when an element needed to be updated, nothing was being done.  By adding the update functions for circles and links when anything changes they will be "updated" to their new position.

```
// ** UPDATE CIRCLES ***
node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

// *** UPDATE LINK ***
link.attr("d", diagonal);
```

Here is the corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t0mhsauf/15/

Hope this helps.